# How to fix "program type already present" error?

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have added the ksoap2 dependency or jar file. I have tried both dependency and library getting this error on pressing the run button of android.

I have explored several links but none worked for me, please give me any appropriate solution.

> error: program type already present: org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception

Comment: do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your app gradle

```
   android {
        ....
        configurations {
             all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
        } 
     }
```